# Salina Cruz, Oaxaca safety?

Tags: safety, mexico, oaxaca

I know Oaxaca is flagged as a travel advisory level 2, but so are a bunch of other places that are fine to travel to. However, [Salina Cruz is called out specifically](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/mexico-travel-advisory.html) as a no go for gov employees. My buddies and I are planning a surf trip down there, is there anything to be acutely aware of besides practicing the normal Mexico tourism "best practices" (try not be out at night, dont flash valuables, etc.).